# How do you generate all n by n matrices mod p in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I am currently trying to figure out what fraction of n by n matrices with elements in F_p are diagonalizable. I am using Matlab for the first time, and I am not quite sure how to generate all matrices with elements in F_p for an n by n matrix of given size, where F_p is the field with p elements. Is there an easy way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: How big are `p` and `n`?  There are `p^(n^2)` such matrices (equivalently, `(p^n)^n`).  Unless `n` is quite small, this becomes a BIG problem.

Comment: I want to find it for large values of n, so as n becomes very large I suppose. I agree this becomes a big problem and I am not so sure matlab will be able to handle it. It already took quite a bit of time for n=5

Comment: I suppose we can keep the values of p relatively small although the question in general has no restrictions on how large they can be. Supposing both were relatively small though, how would one generate all matrices?

Comment: Seems to me this question would better fit math.stackexchange.

Comment: It's the same as generating all `n*n` digit numbers in base `p`, then calling `reshape` to turn the list of digits into a square matrix.